# Jquery Carousel - like plugin / Customization

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, customization, carousel, jcarousel

I'm on a project that will have a slider to show some content, like a carousel.

I remember some time ago (like 2 years back, I think) there was a plugin just like described in the image below. And it made developers fellows life much nicer:

[image: super cool carousel-like slider]

That is: a carousel with a limited number of items showing on the viewport and the centered item was put in evidence with a class or something.
I've searched for hours and coundn't find that plugin anymore. I wonder if someone can remember its name or point me to a similar solution: It needs to be like the image (aligned to the top and mark the centered/active item with a class, so I can style it as needed.

The only one I could find is Sky jQuery Touch Carousel http://www.skyplugins.com/sky-jquery-touch-carousel/default_skin.html. It is pretty good, but it is not quite what I'm looking for, and it is not free.

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT --**

So, my question was market as off topic, even though there is lots of questions with similar subjects here in the community and none of them was treated as such, but whatever... I decided to change the subject a little. I will maintain the original text, so the first answers make sense.

I'm trying to edit jCarousel plugin, to supply this funcionality I need. I have binded a click event to the `li` element, to insert a class on it and successfully styled it. 
Now, everything I have to do is to find a way to center the selected `li` on click, in order to make the element just like the image above.

I have no much experience with the slider logic, so any help would be welcome.

Comment: Try looking through here, http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/12/jquery-carousel.html

Comment: There is good library: http://www.unheap.com/section/media/sliders-carousels/ maybe you'll find there something you'll like

Comment: @Tommi Lots of resources there, thank you. But unfortunately, none of them fits my needs. I changed the subject a little because my question was marked off-topic, and I'm trying to do a little customization to the jCarousel plugin.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/12/jquery-carousel.html) has links to a lot of good plugins.  I had a quick look through.  I'm not sure exactly what you are after but quite a few of them seemed liked the right sort of thing

It could be the case that the plugin you used to use no longer exists or is no longer supported, especially as it was free.